# Potential dangers of enabling classwide globals (Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, global-variables, javascript-objects

I have a question regarding the relative safeness of designing Javascript types that use class static/global variables. For example, suppose we had:

```
function whatever()
{
    if(whatever.initialized === undefined)
    {
        whatever.global_setting = 1024;
        whatever.initialized = true;
    }
}

whatever.prototype.get_global_setting = function()
{
    return whatever.global_setting;
}

whatever.prototype.set_global_setting = function(setting)
{
    whatever.global_setting = setting;
}
```

Now if only one developer/team were to be using the library then whatever nonsense they decide to do on a class-wide scale wouldn't be such a big issue.

But what if we have scripts from several organizations running in a single webpage (ad partners and such) all of which are accessing the library from the same codebase (eg: "XYZ.com/scripts.js")? Will they all get their own private copy or is there even the slightest possibility that it might be shared? If so, then providing an interface for global settings could lead to some pretty serious problems!

**EDIT**

Just to be clear, my library is actually defined more along the lines of this:

```
var whatever = 
(
    function() 
    {
        "use strict";

        function internal_whatever()
        {
            if(internal_whatever.initialized === undefined)
            {
                internal_whatever.global_setting = true;
                internal_whatever.initialized = true;
            }
        }

        internal_whatever.prototype.get_global_setting = function()
        {
            return internal_whatever.global_setting;
        }

        internal_whatever.prototype.set_global_setting = function(setting)
        {
            internal_whatever.global_setting = setting;
        }    

        return internal_whatever;
    }
)();

if(typeof module !== "undefined" && module.hasOwnProperty("exports")) 
{
    module.exports = whatever;
}
```

Does that totally mitigate the issue, or are there still some corner-cases?

Comment: Well, use namespace scope instead of global scope. Like plugins do.

Comment: Okay, I think I may have that covered (see my edit, above). Correct me if I'm wrong though!

Comment: Well this is JavaScript.. everyone can overwrite everything :)

Comment: Looks solid on first sight.

Comment: No, if they're properly wrapped in modules (using whatever pattern), and every user has its own copy of the module, they will get different static values since there are no globals involved.

Comment: Got it! I really didn't want to have to omit this functionality, so that's definitely reassuring...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could use namespace scope instead of global scope. Like plugins do.
Simplified something like this:

```
;var Modules = (Modules === undefined) ? {} : Modules;
Modules.whatever = {
    _nonecares: 1234,

    whatever: function(){
        return this._nonecares
    }
};
console.log(Modules.whatever._nonecares);
```

This is how the newest jquery does it:

```
(function(global, factory){
    "use strict";

    // Pass this if window is not defined yet
})(typeof window !== "undefined" ? window : this, function( window, noGlobal){
    "use strict";

    // Expose jQuery and $ identifiers, even in AMD
    // (#7102#comment:10, https://github.com/jquery/jquery/pull/557)
    // and CommonJS for browser emulators (#13566)
    if( !noGlobal ){
        window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;
    }

    return jQuery;
});
```

Comment: So does that 100% prevent the multiple-use issue I described? And if so, does the way I have it defined now do the same thing as well, or not?

Comment: Well yours is better than mine actually. I thought you were asking more like howto at all. But like I wrote.. it can never be foolproof.. I can always come and write module.exports = alert('haha'); Else it covers pretty much everything.

Comment: Sorry, but when you say "covers pretty much everything", do you mean that there is, in fact, absolutely no chance that multiple parties can possibly get handed the same copy of the library (by the browser)? I'm not concerned with malicious code under these particular circumstances (we'll just blindly assume that all parties can be trusted for the moment). My worry is that a developer from A sets the global setting to a certain value, while one at B (again, whose script is running in the same webpage) assumes the setting to be something else.

Comment: @Sir Galahad: I sadly do not comprehend the question. Of course if developperA sets a global variable to a value everyone has that value at one points - unless the script is not executed. It always has the latest set value. Yet in the shown example of the question, there is no actual global value - it is all in module scope. Then again clients do not interact with each other either - they download the source on their machine and if clientA sets a global value no other client will automatically get that value.

Comment: So in the second example of the question, if every developper just has a different module name, everything is fine - since there are no globals.